# Autoscaling for NetworkLoadBalancedFargateService with CDK?

Tags: python, aws-cdk, aws-fargate, aws-auto-scaling

I have Fargate on a cluster running behind a NLB. I'd like to add autoscaling for it. But I can't find an example for that.

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs.README.html#task-auto-scaling) is the example I found for an `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService`:

```py
fg = aws_ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(...)

scaling = fg.service.auto_scale_task_count(max_capacity=10)
scaling.scale_on_request_count(
    id="RequestScaling",
    requests_per_target=10000,
    target_group=fg.target_group
)
```

But this won't work because the `target_group` parameter expects an instance of `ApplicationTargetGroup` but for `NetworkLoadBalancedFargateService` the `target_group` field is of type `NetworkTargetGroup`.

Answer (score 1):

NLBs don't have a RequestCount metric type just because I guess each TCP connection could contain a number of "requests" in the ALB sense.

In the short term, I think the ActiveFlowCount matches closest with Request Count - so you can use the scaleOnMetric method to scale on ActiveFlowCounit.

In the medium term, I'll try to get a consensus on the best metrics to create a function like ScaleOnRequestType for NLBs.

- https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6887